# SmartPhoto.js is not showing images Correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using smartphoto.js in my code.

```
<div class="slides" data-aos="fade-down">
<a href='<?= $gi['image'] ?>' class="js-smartPhoto" data-caption="LishUp" data-id='<?= $gi['id'] ?>' data-group="0"/>
<img src='<?= $gi['image'] ?>' class="photo" width="auto" height="99%" />
</a>
</div>
```

And ....

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
 new SmartPhoto(".js-smartPhoto", {

}); 
});
```

I have included these scripts and stylesheets

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/smartphoto@1.1.0/js/smartphoto.min.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/smartphoto@1.1.0/css/smartphoto.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.11.0/styles/default.min.css">
```

The code successfully opens the images window but then it goes blank.
You may have noticed I have php code as image link and data-id, those have no problems, they are working correctly.

Please help me

Comment: Is your 'DOMContentLoaded' event listener after the scripts/stylesheets or before?

Comment: @AnthonyMcGrath After the scripts and stylesheets